# Closed geodesics on $K(\pi,1)$ spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold with non-positive sectional curvature, then it is well-known that there are no contractible closed geodesics in $M$. More generally, let $M$ be a closed manifold which is topologically a $K(\pi,1)$ space, is there a Riemannian metric on $M$ so that every closed geodesic in $M$ is non-contractible?

Comment: related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358943/

Comment: Did you think about connected sum of torus with exotic sphere?